# Use Docker for network services

Tags: networking, docker, local-area-network

I know it sounds duplicated, but I can't find my answer on the internet.

It's about 1 year I'm using docker for application development and now I have to handle a local network and I have some questions about using docker in this situation:

Is this good idea to run network services (like `DHCP`, `DNS`, `LDAP`, `HTTP Proxy`, etc.) on docker containers?

I mean instead of running VMs for these services, run some docker host and run thes services on containers.

so I can used docker scalability and high availability and other Docker's feature for my network.

Answer (score 0):

As most of the mentioned functionalities are usually pretty static parts of the network, the services will probably not benefit as much from a containered approach.

Furthermore you might also be adding some extra complexity network-wise when running these services in docker over doing the same with virtualization.

Concerning scalability and high availability you should be able to achieve the same using virtualization.